# Question about Hasse diagram

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Given the partial ordering on set A ={$a,b,c,d$} as
{$(a,a),(b,b),(a,c),(a,b),(a,d),(c,d)$},

Draw the Hasse Diagram.
Why $(a,a)$and$(b,b)$ can be shown in the Hasse diagram?

Comment: Show your work, even partial work is fine. Draw what you think the Hasse diagram should be and we'll check it.

Comment: Your set is not a valid partial order.  Where is $(c,c)$ and $(d,d)$?

Comment: The hasse diagram shouldn't need to picture loops like $(a,a)$ and $(b,b)$ because *every* element is supposed to be related to itself in a partial order.  There would be no point in picturing that when it can already be known ahead of time by the nature of what partial orders are in the first place.  If we were to include that in the picture, it would just make it more difficult to read for no benefit.